# YASM is there a way to check for specific numbers in a word?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, yasm, hammingweight

If I were to try to calculate the number of 1's in the dw data, how would I go about that? I want to store the number of 1's in memory sum. I am using EBE to code in 64 bit Assembly Language.

```
segment .data
       data     dw  1011011011001010b
       sum  dq  0
       size     db  16

segment .text
global main
main:
```

Comment: Sufficiently modern CPUs have the `POPCNT` instruction which does exactly this: `popcnt ax, word [data]` will leave 9 in `ax`.

Comment: For lots of other algorithms, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/how-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer/109025#109025

Answer (score 1):

Below is a simple code that counts the **1**'s in the datum:

```
  movzx edx, word [data]
  xor   eax, eax           ; RAX=0 CF=0
more:
  adc   eax, 0
  shr   edx, 1
  jnz   more
  adc   eax, 0
  mov   [sum], rax
```

And this snippet counts the **0**'s in the value at *data*. It works by subtracting the number of 1's from the number of available bits in *data* (stored in *size*).

```
  movzx edx, word [data]
  movzx eax, byte [size]
  clc                      ; Keeps first SBB from subtracting (first time only)
more:
  sbb   eax, 0
  shr   edx, 1
  jnz   more
  sbb   eax, 0
  mov   [sum], rax
```